# How do you create a computed property in Ember.js to see if a single Ember Data attribute is dirty?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, computed-properties

I've tried creating a computed property on an Ember Data 1.13.16 model like this:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  isNameDirty: Ember.computed('name', 'hasDirtyAttributes', function() {
    return !!this.changedAttributes()['name'];
  })
});
```

But for some reason, after calling `model.save()` the property never recomputes to false, even though `name` is no longer present in `changedAttributes()`. How can I make this computed property work?

Here's a reduced test case: https://ember-twiddle.com/87b1af7abfb103554cb2?openFiles=models.author.js%2C

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe it's due to the `hasDirtyAttributes` not being consumed anywhere, meaning the change observers won't be properly set up.

A simple fix is:

```
isNameDirty: Ember.computed('name', 'hasDirtyAttributes', function() {
  if (!this.get('hasDirtyAttributes')) { return false; }
  return !!this.changedAttributes()['name'];
})
```

This ensures that `hasDirtyAttributes` property is consumed and that this property will be updated when that other property changes. In general, if you have a property as a dependent key, you should definitely be `get`ting it in the computed function body, and if you are `get`ting a property in the function body, it should always be listed as a dependent key. I believe the reason it works this way is due to performance optimisations.